# Evento de botão no Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com Yii Framework que é relativamente simples.
Primeiro fiz uma view chamada `total.php`, que pede uma `data inicial`, `data final` e um botão:

```
<?php 
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'impressoes-do-usuario-form-teste3-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); 
?>
<div class="wide form">
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'dataInicio'); ?>
   <?php $this->widget('CMaskedTextField', array(
       'mask'=>'99-99-9999', 
       'model'=>$model, 
       'attribute'=>'dataInicio',
       'value' => (empty($model->dataInicio) ? $model->dataInicio : '31/03/1987'),
    ));?>
</div>
<div class="wide form">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'dataFim'); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('CMaskedTextField', array(
        'mask'=>'99-99-9999', 
        'model'=>$model, 
        'attribute'=>'dataFim'
    ));?>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('OK');?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

O meu controller é o `JobsLogController`, e a action é a `actionTotal`:

```
<?php

class JobsLogController extends Controller
{
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';
    public $defaultAction = "total";

    public function actionTotal()
    {


        $model = new ImpressoesDoUsuarioForm;
        $impressoras = null;    

        if (isset($_POST['ImpressoesDoUsuarioForm']))
        {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['ImpressoesDoUsuarioForm'];

            // CONVERTENDO AS DATAS
            $dataInicio = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', strtotime($model->dataInicio));
            $dataFim    = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', strtotime($model->dataFim));

            // BUSCA POR TODAS AS IMPRESSORAS NA DATA ESCOLHIDA
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->select='printer';
            $criteria->distinct=true;
            $criteria->condition='date>:dataInicio AND date<:dataFim';
            $criteria->params=array(":dataInicio"=>$dataInicio,":dataFim"=>$dataFim);
            $printers = JobsLog::model()->findAll($criteria);
            array_multisort($printers,SORT_ASC);

            $impressoras = array();

            // BUSCA IMPRESSOES DO USUARIO NA IMPRESSORA
            foreach($printers as $printer)
            {
                $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->select='user';
                $criteria->distinct=true;
                $criteria->condition='printer=:printer AND date>:dataInicio AND date<:dataFim';
                $criteria->params=array(":printer"=>$printer->printer,
                            ":dataInicio"=>$dataInicio,
                            ":dataFim"=>$dataFim);

                $users = JobsLog::model()->findAll($criteria);

                $impressoes = array();

                foreach($users as $user)
                {
                    $criteria->select='*';
                    $criteria->condition='user=:user AND printer=:impressora AND date>:dataInicio AND date<:dataFim';
                    $criteria->params=array(":user"=>$user->user,
                                ":impressora"=>$printer->printer,
                                ":dataInicio"=>$dataInicio,
                                "dataFim"=>$dataFim);

                    $impressoesDoUsuario = JobsLog::model()->findAll($criteria);
                    $contagem = 0;
                    foreach($impressoesDoUsuario as $impressaoDoUsuario)
                    {
                        $contagem += $impressaoDoUsuario->copies * $impressaoDoUsuario->pages;  
                    }
                    $impressoes[$user->user] = $contagem;
                }
                $impressoras[$printer->printer] = $impressoes;
            }

        }
        $this->render('total',array("model"=>$model,"impressoras"=>$impressoras));

    }
}
?>
```

Meu problema é que não sei como chamar a action `actionTotal` através do botão que criei em `total.php`. Alguém sabe como eu faço isso nesse framework? Procurei na documentação, mas não tive sucesso.

Obrigado!

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente, você esta utilizando um Framework [MVC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc), então tome cuidado com acessos diretos ao banco de dados no seu controlador.

Dito isso podemos continuar. Para fazer com que o seu botão execute uma ação do controller, você pode utilizar de diversas formas. Uma delas é efetuando o submit do formulário.

Quando você utiliza apenas o comando`CHtml::submitButton('OK');`, você esta dizendo que o formulário será enviado para a action atual, ou seja, a action que chamou esta página.

Para mudar isso é fácil, utilizando a variável `'action'` do widget `CActiveForm` desta forma([ref1](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#action-detail)):

```
<?php 
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'impressoes-do-usuario-form-teste3-form',
        'action' => array('JobsLog/total'),
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); 
?>
```

Você também pode fazer isso reescrevendo o botão, direcionando nele([ref2](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh2)):

```
<?php echo CHtml::button('OK', array('submit' => array('JobsLog/total'))); ?>
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.